# R - Flextable and paging (or rollbars)

Tags: html, r, datatable, r-markdown, flextable

**Q/** Is there a way to have **paging** or **rollbars** using the package **flextable** in R ?

I know it's possible with the package **DT**. I didn't find the answer on the documentation or the vignette for flextable. As this package is for publication, maybe it is not its purpose to propose such a functionnality.

The objective is to print a table with a lot of rows, but without taking a lot of place in the html.

```
library(DT)
DT::datatable(mtcars)
```

[image]

```
library(flextable)
flextable::flextable(mtcars)
# the whole table will be printed
```

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry sir. There is not a way to do that with the package DT. You'll need to download the package TSP and use
library(TSP)
TSP::solute.mtcars
TSP::datatable(mtcars)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you mean *flextable* and not *DT* ? (because it is possible with DT)